# Get Server IP address from JSP Request/session object

Tags: java, jsp, request, ip-address, response

How can I get the IP address of the server from a JSP page?

Right now, all I can do is request.getLocalName(), which returns the server name, not the IP address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, for the IP address of the *server*, you need to use

```
String serverIP = request.getLocalAddr();
```

Comment: Thanks. Why didn't I see that on the javadoc? @_@

Comment: @portoalet: May not have been overlooking it. getLocalAddr() was added for the 2.4 version of the servlet spec (I believe the first result in Google is the Javadoc for Java EE 1.3)

Comment: Ten years later: `<%= request.getLocalAddr() %>` with `JSP` using Apache Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 3):

```
String sIPAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: This retrieves the IP of the client that initiated the request.

Answer (score 3):

To get an actual server IP and hostname (actual and not set by e.g. a proxy) use this:

```
            <%@ page import="java.net.*" %> 
            [...]
            <%
            String hostname, serverAddress;
            hostname = "error";
            serverAddress = "error";
            try {
                InetAddress inetAddress;
                inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                hostname = inetAddress.getHostName();
                serverAddress = inetAddress.toString();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            %>
            <li>InetAddress: <%=serverAddress %>
            <li>InetAddress.hostname: <%=hostname %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String addr = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR")
```